# JPA query return List<org.datanucleus.store.types.sco.backed.ArrayList> instead List<T>

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa, datanucleus

I'm using JPA on GAE and this query return a List containing 1 element.
This element is a org.datanucleus.store.types.sco.backed.ArrayList (and it's finally containing my results) while I'm expecting a List of Products. What I'm doing wrong?
Thanx in advance!

```
Query query = entityManager.createQuery
             ("select p.products from Place p where p.id = :Id" );
query.setParameter("Id",id);
    List<Product> resultList = query.getResultList();
    //for debugging purpose
    assert (resultList.get(0) instanceof Product);
    if (resultList.size() > 0)
    {
        //raise a cast exception here
        Product p = resultList.get(0);
    }
```

---

```
@Entity
public class Place {

    private Collection<Product> products;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public Collection<Product> getProducts() {
        return products;
    }

    public void setProducts(Collection<Product> products) {
        this.products = products;
    }

    private String id;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Extension(vendorName="datanucleus", key="gae.encoded-pk", value="true")
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

Comment: Does not that class extend `List`?

Comment: @SJuan76 That class implements `List` & extends a class which again extend `Arraylist`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selecting a multi-valued field from a JPQL query is illegal when the JPQL spec says the select item should be

```
"single_valued_path_expression | scalar_expression | aggregate_expression | 
    identification_variable | OBJECT(identification_variable) | constructor_expression"
```

so answers saying this query is correct are wrong. If you want the "products" for a Place then you retrieve the Place and it has the products.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, that solve my question. Regarding of the way of retrieving the data, because of the lazy loading, I suppose that access to place.getProducts() will cause another request to the datastore. So a query.getSingleResult() could be my best choice.

Comment: @DataNucleus The query works with JPA, can select Product entity directly without querying Place entity, not sure about datanucleus.

Comment: @Nayan, It is a multi-valued field, so no it is not part of the JPA spec. Obviously DataNucleus JPA passes the JPA TCK.

Comment: @DataNucleus I have tried & it worked, fetched directly list of child entities.

Comment: @DataNucleus Correct me if wrong, else rephrase your post accordingly.

Comment: @Nayan, my comment is very clear. The JPA spec does not define support for selecting multivalued fields. I even quoted the part of the spec. Whether some implementation supports it is a completely different question

Comment: @DataNucleus I presume you haven't tried & believed in specification. Anyways, no issues with that, my clarifications ends here.

Comment: Some people value sticking to the spec, since it means they have real portability. It means they don't base their app on vendor extensions that would fail if they ever move the app to a different implementation. And indeed that's all my answer says. What your problem with that is I've no idea

Answer (score 1):

I am not much familiar with DataNucleus, so haven't executed. But with JPA, the query should work fine. You can try the below code to build query, which returns results according to the specified class.

```
entityManager.createQuery("SELECT p.products FROM Place p WHERE p.id = :Id", Product.class);
```

**From Documentation :**

```
<T> TypedQuery<T> createQuery(java.lang.String qlString,
                                      java.lang.Class<T> resultClass)
```

> Create an instance of TypedQuery for executing a Java Persistence
>   query language statement. The select list of the query must contain
>   only a single item, which must be assignable to the type specified by
>   the resultClass argument.

```
Parameters:
         qlString - a Java Persistence query string
         resultClass - the type of the query result
```

---

**Edit :**
You can try the following code.

```
Place place = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Place p WHERE p.id = :Id", Place.class).getSingleResult();

List<Products> products = place.getProducts();
```

Also as a side-note, you are using JPA, but `@Extension` seems to be JDO specific annotation.

Comment: Thanks Nayan, I've already tried, but specifying the return class cause a CastException...

Comment: @Fabio Edited post accordingly, might help you

Comment: Thanks for the tip of using getSingleResult().
Regarding @Extension annotation there's the JPA counterpart, to avoid use google datastore Key type.

Answer (score 0):

That class javadoc tells that it implements `java.util.List`, so it is a valid return type.

Remember that the specification says that you get a `List` as a return type, not a `java.util.ArrayList`, so any class that implements `List` is as valid as any other.

UPDATE:

Try:

```
 SELECT pr FROM Place pl INNER JOIN pl.products pr WHERE pl.id = :Id
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't make clear my problem... I'll edit the question

Comment: Tnx again, didn't tried, but on GAE you can't use join, so probably it's not applicable to my environment